# Ordering an array in javascript by the most common item

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings:

```
array = ["Henry","Brian","Henry","Matilda","Henry","Brian","Matthew"]
```

And want to sort them into a list which orders the array by the most commonly occuring items first, but then also deletes them afterwards to create a list like so:

```
sortedArray = ["Henry","Brian","Matilda","Matthew"]
```

Is there a way of doing this in javascript?

Comment: Sure, there are ways. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried? You'll need to do it in two phases: First determining the number of occurrences, then filtering and ordering the result. You should also probably beware that you're going to get lots of answers that happily throw efficiency out the window for conciseness, so if that matters, you might want to mention it.

Comment: I haven't as of yet, my knowledge of javascript is very basic, it is very helpful to think of the problem broken down as you have suggested!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this ES6 function which runs in *O(nlogn)*, not *O(n²)* as some other solutions:

```js
var array = ["Henry","Brian","Henry","Matilda","Henry","Brian","Matthew"]

var result = [...array.reduce( (acc, s) => acc.set(s, (acc.get(s) || 0)+1), new Map )]
    .sort( (a, b) => b[1] - a[1] )
    .map( a => a[0] );

console.log(result);
```

It first creates a map, by keeping a count for each string (runs in linear time).

Then this map is transformed to an array of pairs (with spread `[...  ]`), which is then sorted ( *O(nlogn)* ) by that count.

Finally, the count is dropped again from that array, using `.map()`

Comment: This is pretty cool, though perhaps a tad opaque from the maintainability perspective.  Still, I like it, +1.

Comment: Thank you, this is a really neat solution - thank you for explaining it well too!

Answer (score 3):

First create `hash table` with the array elements and the number of occurences - then sort it.

See demo below:

```js
var array = ["Henry","Brian","Henry","Matilda","Henry","Brian","Matthew"];

var hash = array.reduce(function(p,c) {
  p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1;
  return p;
},{});

// console.log(hash);

var result = Object.keys(hash).sort(function(a,b){
  return hash[b] - hash[a];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.sort((a, b) => 
   array.filter(e => e === b).length -  array.filter(e=> e === a).length  
)
```

Then , remove duplicated items  :

```
[... new Set(array)]
```

```js
let array = ["Henry", "Brian", "Henry", "Matilda", "Henry", "Brian", "Matthew"]


array = array.sort((a, b) =>
  array.filter(e => e === b).length - array.filter(e => e === a).length
)

console.log(
  [...new Set(array)]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count all items and sort the keys later with the count descending.

```js
var array = ["Henry", "Brian", "Henry", "Matilda", "Henry", "Brian", "Matthew"],
    count = Object.create(null),
    result;

array.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a] = (count[a] || 0) + 1;
});

result = Object.keys(count).sort(function (a, b) { return count[b] - count[a]; });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice, as always ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the hash method should be fastest, yet here is another way which utilizes `.findIndex()` to run only among the unique items which might turn out to be not so bad as well. It just swaps the unique items array (`p`) with the previous one if it's length is bigger than the previous one.

```js
var data = ["Henry","Brian","Henry","Matilda","Henry","Brian","Matthew","Matthew","John","Matthew"],
  result = data.reduce(function(p,c){
                         var fi = p.findIndex(f => f[0] === c);
                         return fi === -1 ? (p.push([c]), p)
                                          : (p[fi].push(c),
                                             fi ? (p[fi].length > p[fi-1].length && ([p[fi-1],p[fi]] = [p[fi],p[fi-1]]),p)
                                                : p);
                                    },[])
               .map(e => e[0]);
console.log(result);
```